# Linking functions with different return types

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, linkage, function-declaration

**0.c**

```
int test();
int main(){
 return test();
}
```

**1.c**

```
void test(){
 //
}
```

Above compiles fine with `gcc 0.c 1.c` and main returns `0`.
Is this undefined behaviour? as `test` technically doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Unlike C++, C doesn't include the function parameters or return types in its linkage information. So the linker won't detect this error.

Comment: @Barmar changing file type to `cc` and doing `g++ 0.cc 1.cc` also compiles.

Comment: I doubt that. Function overloading depends on giving different names depending on the types.

Comment: But overloading is only based on argument types, so maybe it doesn't distinguish return types.

Comment: @Barmar yes seems like it's only effective on argument types.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's what I thought, but the OP says he tried it and it linked.

Comment: Just try it on your machines. I've tried with g++ and clang++, it compiles.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, I should have tested it before posting. It does link successfully because the return type isn't part of the signature checked by the linker. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: I just confirmed that it compiles with g++ on MacOS Monterey.

Comment: I guess regardless of it being linked, it's all UB.

Comment: That is not a full prototype, as it is missing argument types, in this case, `void`.

Comment: OT: This is a fine example why it is best practice to include the header with the prototype in the implementation, too. The compiler will warn you quite early.

Comment: compiled with GCC: *gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" 
untitled.c:8:6: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
    8 | void test(){
      |      ^~~~
untitled.c:1:5: note: previous declaration of ‘test’ was here
    1 | int test();
      |     ^~~~*
Compilation failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opposite to C++ C does not stores in external names of functions their return types and argument types. It only specifies that (relative to the provided code) there is an external name of the function `test` used for linkage.

As for C++ then for example in the documentation for MS VC++ there is written about decorated names

> **If you change the function name, class, calling convention, return type, or any parameter, the decorated name also changes**. In this
> case, you must get the new decorated name and use it everywhere the
> decorated name is specified.

Decorated names are implementation-defined in C++.

As a result the provided code in the question has undefined behavior.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, changing file types to cc and doing `g++ 0.cc 1.cc` also compiles. Is it compiler specific?

Comment: C++ linker seems to only be effective on argument types, not return types.

Comment: Either way even if it compiles it's still UB then.

Comment: @Dan The linker for a C++ program should issue an error message.

Comment: Try the above snippets with g++, it doesn't issue an error, it only does so if arguments differ.

Comment: @Dan Decorated names in C++ are changed from version to version.

Comment: The quoted documentation is for MS VC++. GCC and Clang don't include the return type in the decorated name.

Comment: @Barmar I wrote that this dependents on the compiler version.

Comment: I thought you meant version numbers, e.g. it changes between v1 and v2.